# How do I chain multiple rename functions in SWIG?

Tags: swig

I have a number of classes that I'd like to rename in SWIG. Most of my classes look like this
`some_class`, which I'd like to rename to `SomeClass`. This is easy:

`%replace("%(camelcase)s", %$isclass) "";`

However, I also have class names that end in "_t" which I'd like to strip, so `my_class_t` would become just `MyClass`. I can do just this operation with:

`%rename("%(regex:/^(.*)(_t?)$/\\1/)s", %$isclass) "";`

Is there a rename rule that will let me apply both of these actions?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot apply multiple rename-s to a single identifier.

Comment: The first rename is fairly easy to decipher but the second one is unmaintainable, not worth it. Rename each individually. If you have a huge # of classes to rename, you're better off creating a script that generates the %rename lines for you; you can then document each operation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can chain multiple renames, but you can send the found string to an external process and do whatever you want there.

[Advanced renaming support](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_advanced_renaming)

> **command:cmd**
>
> Output of an external command cmd with the string passed to it as
>   input. Notice that this function is extremely slow compared to all the
>   other ones as it involves spawning a separate process and using it for
>   many declarations is not recommended. The cmd is not enclosed in
>   square brackets but must be terminated with a triple '<' sign, e.g.
>   %rename("command:tr -d aeiou <<<") (nonsensical example removing all
>   vowels)

Comment: Note that `command:cmd` has been removed in SWIG 4.1: https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/v4.1.0/CHANGES.current#L819-L840